# getting wrong line number when raising java exception

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to create code where if an Application Error is found, an Exception is thrown. The idea was that I could also get the line number where the error took place.

What I have now is as follows:

```
try {
    // ...
    if ( customerid <= 0 ) throw new ApplicationError( " =>invalid customerid  passed in" );
    // ...
}
catch ( ApplicationError e )
{

            throw new RuntimeError(" => CLASS :  "
                    + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " => LINE : "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]
                    + " => MESSAGE : " + e.getMessage()
                    + " => CAUSED BY : " + e.getCause());
}
```

Just as a note, I have created an exception called RuntimeError whose only purpose is to print any error messages found.

But ...
The problem is that in the code,
The part: `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]` returns the line number that thee code `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]` is on.

Not the line number that throw new `ApplicationError( " =>invalid customer passed in );` is on

I have tried using:

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[0] and
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2]
```

but none of these have worked. Java 1.7 is being used now - but the idea is to go to 1.8 a quite a bit later.

How can this be fixed?

**Update**

Removed as per the request of @Jean-Baptiste Yunès  I have resolved the second issue on my own.

Comment: Can you show sample output of the full stack trace? And please provide the class name and line numbers of this snippet.

Comment: `e.getStackTrace()`

Comment: Don't edit a question to add two more question. Ask one question per post...

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple of things wrong here. First, don't name exceptions as errors. An `Error` means that things are **really** wrong, like server on fire (or `OutOfMemoryError`). `RuntimeException` is fine to use and extend.

Secondly and more importantly, you're essentially making it harder for yourself to debug the exception by removing most of the information from the stacktrace. If you have a problem in the software, you want to see the *whole* callstack, not just the lowest point where the exception happened. Therefore you really shouldn't be catching `ApplicationError` at all (you're only replacing it with a different exception), but propagate it upwards. If `ApplicationError` is a checked exception (in which case it's misleadingly named) and you wan't to convert it to an unchecked one, then you should do just

```
try {
    ...
} catch(ApplicationError e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: "If you have a problem in the software, you want to see the whole callstack" - so how could one see this? In my case, what would I put if the customer does not exist? Are you saying to remove the "catch ( ApplicationError e )" block and just let it "bubble up" to the top?

Comment: Well you're bubbling it up at the moment too, except you remove all the important information and change the exception type. If you have a `e.printStackTrace()` somewhere higher up, that'll print it to the console, a better way is to use a logging framework to generate log files.

Comment: I made an update to the post (referencing something you said.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` catches the stack trace of the current instruction... If you want to get the stack trace of the exception thrown you caught in `e` then use `e.getStackTrace()`.

As @kayaman says, don't use errors...

Comment: OK - I see what you are saying - it makes sense. I now trying to the information that shows the line number when running e.getStackTrace()

Comment: This is not in the spirit of Java, use something like `e.getStackTrace().getLineNumber()`...